# If $E/\mathbb{Q}$ is an elliptic curve and $j(E)=0$ then $y^2=x^3+D$ for some $6$-th power free integer $D$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am self studying Silverman's arithmetic of elliptic curves book and I am trying to solve exercise 10.19. It has four parts, and I was able to do everything but the first one. Here is the problem:

**Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve such that $j(E)=0$. Prove that there is a unique integer $D$ which is $6$-th powe free such that $E$ can be written as $y^2=x^3+D$.**

I know that an elliptic curve can be written as $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ with $4A^3+27B^2\neq 0$ and that $j(E)=1728 \frac{4A^3}{4A^3+27B^2}$ hence $j(E)=0$ implies $A=0$ and so we have that $E$ can be written as $y^2=x^3+B$ where $B\neq0$. Also it is trivial to see that $B$ can be taken to be $6$-th power free by making a change of variable. Hence, there is only one thing left to prove:

- If we have two elliptic cuves $y^2=x^3+D$ and $y^2=x^3+D'$ with $D\neq D'$ both $6$-th power free integers then they are not isomorphic curves.

But I don't have any clue on how to prove this, since there might be a tricky change of variables and I don't know a general method to show when two elliptic curves are not isomorphic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In general, the reduced short Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ determines the curve up to isomorphism. By reduced, I mean that there is no prime $p$ such that $p^4\mid A$ and $p^6\mid B$. You can prove this by hand: any change of variables has to be of the form $x=u^2x' + r$ and $y = u^3y'+su^2x' + t$. It's easy to show that $s$, $t$ and $r$ have to be $0$ for the curve to remain in short Weierstrass form, and the reduced assumption then forces $u=1$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thanks.... shomehow I forgot this result, but this is something I've seen, so the result become obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the claim is quite true as stated, that these are non-isomorphic for $D \neq D'$; I think the requirement should be that $D \neq D'$ as elements of $\mathbb{Q}^\times / (\mathbb{Q}^\times)^6$. (EDIT: since $D$ and $D'$ are integers, though, these are the same, see comment.)

If that's right, here is a sketch of an ugly but reasonably concrete proof.

First note that the curves become isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$. Choose and write down an isomorphism $\phi_{D, D'}$ explicitly. Then every isomorphism between them over $\mathbb{C}$ is a composition of $\phi_{D, D'}$ and an automorphism.

The automorphisms of $y^2 = x^3 + D$ are the six maps of the form $x \mapsto \zeta^i x$ and $y \mapsto \pm y$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive third root of unity and $i \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$.

Compute these compositions explicitly and observe that none comes from a map of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: can you give me a counterexample of $D\neq D'$ such that the curves are isomorphic? My intuition tells me that it should be true.

Comment: @Marcos I think you are right, now. Since $D$ and $D'$ are integers (which I hadn't been paying attention to), the only way to have $p^6 | D'D^{-1}$ is to have $p^6 | D$, which has been ruled out. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Nice, one last question. Why every isomorphism can be writen as an automorphism times a fixed isomorphism? Is that an standard fact? Where can I find a proof of this fact?

Comment: @Marcos this is actually true in any category -- if X and Y are objects and phi: X \to Y is an isomorphism, then any other  isomorphism can be written as phi followed by an automorphism of Y. The proof is straigtforward: if phi and psi are two different isomorphisms from X to Y, then you get an automorphism of Y by "going around the circle" (psi inverse circle phi)

Comment: Ohh, I see, so elegant and interesting result. Thanks!!!!